# Как вывести страну и цену доставки в карточку товара opencart?

Tags: opencart

Как вывести страну и цену доставки в карточку товара opencart, как
[здесь](https://az.fromae.com/ru/lg-v30-plus-dual-h930ds-128gb-4g-lte-black?___store=az_ru&___from_store=az_az).

Comment: Уточните вопрос, вам нужно получить данные с этого сайта, или добавить что то похожее на свой?

Comment: добавить похожее на свой.Нужно определить страну и вывести цену доставки.Модулей нормальных вроде нет  на 2.3

Comment: Ну тогда я незнаю, интернет-магазинами не увлекаюсь.